# can't find a newly created secret in a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

First I create a **namespace** "foo" using this .yaml file :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: foo
```

```
tomas@ubunt:~$ kubectl apply -f namespace.yaml 
namespace/foo created
```

I then create a **secret** that is connected to this "foo" namespace using this .yaml file :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: bar
  namespace: foo
type: Opaque
data:
    mongo-root-username: bW9uZ29kYg==
    mongo-root-password: Y29tbWFuZCA=
```

```
tomas@ubunt:~/minikub/false$ kubectl apply -f secret.yaml 
secret/bar created
```

If I try to get more info about this secret it says there's no secret "bar":

```
tomas@ubunt:~$ kubectl get secret bar -o yaml
Error from server (NotFound): secrets "bar" not found
```

How come do I get this result when I have just created this secret and I got an output saying it was created.

Answer (score 1):

To get more info about the secret you also have to specify the namespace you have created your  secret in and you do it like so :

`kubectl -n foo get secret bar -o yaml`